# SELECT запрос в зависимости от результатов предыдущего SELECT запроса

Tags: sql, база-данных, sqlite

Как написать SELECT запрос, который будет выполнятся только в том случае, если предыдущий SELECT возвратит ноль строк?

Comment: Приведите пример запросов

Comment: @JVic,select * from adress where default_obj=1,если он вернул 0 строк то выполнить select * from adress

Comment: where not exists(второй запрос)

Comment: @msi,что-то туплю.Можно готовую версию запроса(1 запрос-  select * from adress where default_obj=1  а 2-   select * from adress )

Comment: @mr.robot, - select * from adress where default_obj=1 union all select * from adress where not exists (select * from adress where default_obj=1)

Comment: @msi,запиши это в ответы,помечу как правильный

Comment: @mr.robot, хорошо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from adress where default_obj=1 
union all 
select * from adress where not exists (select * from adress where default_obj=1)
```

Comment: сработало,благодарю

Answer (score 0):

> **В комментариях утверждается, что этот ответ ошибочен!**

Возможно, БД догадается выполнить оптимизацию такого запроса:

```
select top 1 from
(
  select top 1 * from smth where id = 90
  union all
  select top 1 * from smth where id = 200
)
```

Comment: порядок выдачи union в общем случае не определен, особенно если БД догадается выполнить оптимизацию ... без order by нельзя гарантировать ничего. тогда уж лучше `id in(90,200)` с `order by case when id=90 ...`

Comment: @Mike, всегда считал, что union выполняются подряд. Разве нет?

Comment: Фактически union all выполняются действительно по очереди. Но ни одним стандартом это не оговаривается. Но это касается именно all и то, СУБД имеет право поменять свое поведение, если ей так будет удобнее. А без all происходит фактически группировка (для удаления повторов), после нее о порядке судить сложно

Comment: @Mike, дописал `all`. А для `order by` ведь часть запроса не будет выкидываться?

Comment: all лишь повышает шансы, что порядок будет такой. возможно в sqlite это так и есть (а может и нет). Но в более серьезных СУБД порядок может зависеть от решения оптимизатора. он может например решить выполнить части запроса в разных потоках, а потом объединить результат. заботиться при этом о порядке СУБД не будет, потому что стандарты гарантируют порядок только в случае применения order by

Comment: @Mike, странно, конечно, но ладно...